# How do I get the memory usage and cpu time of a process executed using ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, python, processbuilder, memory-consumption, cpu-time

I am executing python/perl scripts on java using processBuilder.
I want to know the memory usage and CPU time for the process executed.
Java mx bean is limited to jvm. Hence ,I don't think it can be used for script executions.
Please help.

Comment: are you on windows or on linux?

Comment: I am using linux.
However, I want to get the cpu time and memory usage for any script run using processBuilder regardless of the OS.( if not, please give me for both linux and windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 9 or later, use `Process::info()` to get the `ProcessHandle.Info` object for the process (if available).  Depending on what the JVM supports on your OS platform, that may give you the total CPU time for the process, and the processes start time ... which you can use to calculate the elapsed time, under some circumstances.

---

Another alternative on a Linux system is to execute the command as "/usr/bin/time your command", and parse the last three lines of standard output to get the elapsed time, "user" CPU time and "system" CPU time.

For example:

```
$ time date
Thu Jul  5 20:25:01 AEST 2018

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Capture and parse the last 3 lines.  (Implementing this in Java is left as an exercise ...)

The GNU version of the `time` command has options that can be used to show memory usage as well.  This is described in the manual entry.

Some equivalent commands for Windows are described here:

- https://superuser.com/questions/228056/windows-equivalent-to-unix-time-command

---

For the record, this (roughly speaking) is the way use `time` using ProcessBuilder:

```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
           "sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/time python filename.py");
```

or

```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
           "/usr/bin/time python filename.py");
```

If you are going to run commands in a subshell using "sh -c", the shell input string must be a *single command argument*.  Since `ProcessBuilder` doesn't understand quoting, this means that you must do the splitting yourself; see above.

To get the GNU time to output the memory parameters, you need to use a format string, as described in "man time"; e.g.

```
  /usr/bin/time -f "%e %s %u %M" command to be run
```

Note that it is important to use "/usr/bin/time" rather than "time", since the builtin "time" command in some shells doesn't understand the "-f" option.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Also, How can I generate the memory usage?

Comment: I have answered that.  Use the relevant options in the GNU version of `time` as described in the `time` manual entry.  I don't think you can do that using the `info()` approach (yet).

Comment: neither processBuilder nor getRuntime.exec understand gnu commands.
So ,I'm not able to use your suggested method. Are there any other alternatives?
can javaMX bean be used to calculate the cputime of a process executed using ProcessBuilder?

Comment: 1) It is the OS ... not exec ... that needs to understand the commands. And Linux **does** understand GNU time.  (Run this: `/usr/bin/time --version`).  Perhaps you should share your attempted code.  2) AFAIK, nothing practical. 3) No.

Comment: /usr/bin/time --version is giving
GNU time 1.7.
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("csh -c time python filename.py"); 
is working.
however, when I change this to 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("csh -c time -p python filename.py");
or ("csh -c /usr/bin/time  python filename.py"), only the python script is running without including the time.
I am not able to obtain the memory usage because of this.
Please help!